# LibGDX (Scene2D): Using Table with Labels to do a chat menu

Tags: user-interface, libgdx, chat, scene2d

I am trying to do a chat menu in my game using a Table and Labels but I can't seem to get the labels to behave the way I want them to.

By default they are drawn in the middle of the table. I added this settings to fix that but now when I add new labels they expand to fill the table, which I don't want.

After adding settings:
[image]

After adding a new label:
[image]
Note: The second message is there, it's jsut very faint. Just another bug I am having :/

Also,  you may notice that the "Send" button is half off screen, trying to fix that too, but one problem at a time I guess.

By the way, the table is within a ScrollPane.

Comment: Can't find the issue with your code without seeing your code...

Comment: Could you also post pictures with debugAll() turned on?

Comment: Here is the window's code from the game's github: https://github.com/vedi0boy/Archipelo/blob/master/core/src/net/hollowbit/archipelo/screen/screens/gamescreen/ChatWindow.java. I added debug all images

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I would have used a text area in a scroll pane and added text rather than adding labels in table.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. It wounds like it makes more sense. Thank you

Comment: I looked into TextAreas and they seem more designed for Text input, and not tex display. It's basically a big TextField.